# Parent with empty groups problem. Cloth

Tags: rigging, cloth-simulation, parent, empty

To make the simulation easier when adding the pants, I moved the character's legs a bit in pose mode. Then, with the whole rig selected in pose mode, I hit ctrl A and "apply selected as rest pose".
Once I want to parent the "Empty groups" pants (to later transfer the weights in weight painting mode), the pants are placed wrong (and it is not the same position as the "original")[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=AbEz9nDx" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/AbEz9nDx/)

Answer (score 0):

Your armature is currently not in *Rest* pose, so as soon as you'll parent your pants, they'll move to a unwanted position. What you need to do is first bring back your armature to *Rest Position*:

[image]

As you can see the pants are not aligned with the armature anymore, to realign them, you can for example switch to *Sculpt* mode, and correct the shape of the pants so that it matches the rest of the body (for example you can use the *Pose* brush):

[image]

Then parent *With Automatic Weights*.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot! I'll try to do it.